# Azure - NoSuchMethodExist error in ApplicationTokenCredential while trying to get key from keyVault

Tags: java, azure, azure-eventhub, azure-keyvault

I am trying to get key in this way:

```
private static String getPolicyKey(String secretName, String keyVaultUrl, String applicationId, String applicationSecret) {
  KeyVaultClient keyVaultClient = new KeyVaultClient(new ApplicationTokenCredentials(
        applicationId,          // Application ID
        "myDomain.com",                                 // Azure Active Directory Domain
        applicationSecret,  // Application Key Value
        AzureEnvironment.AZURE
  ));

  return keyVaultClient.getSecret(
        keyVaultUrl,        // KeyValut URL
        secretName   // Secret Name
  ).value();
}
```

But I am getting an Exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials.proxy()Ljava/net/Proxy;

at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials.acquireAccessToken(ApplicationTokenCredentials.java:137)
at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.ApplicationTokenCredentials.getToken(ApplicationTokenCredentials.java:127)
at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentials.getToken(AzureTokenCredentials.java:39)
at com.microsoft.azure.credentials.AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.intercept(AzureTokenCredentialsInterceptor.java:36)
at okhttp3.RealCall$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(RealCall.java:190)
at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:163)
at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:57)
at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.execute(OkHttpCall.java:174)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$RequestArbiter.request(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:171)
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:211)
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:152)
at retrofit2.adapter.rxjava.RxJavaCallAdapterFactory$CallOnSubscribe.call(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.java:138)
at rx.Observable.unsafeSubscribe(Observable.java:10142)
```

I am using the following dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-eventhubs</artifactId>
            <version>0.15.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-keyvault</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-client-authentication</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Note: I tried with azure-eventhubs version 1.0.1 but even that gave same error.

This is my first time dealing with azure-eventhubs, any kind of direction on this will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Look for incompatible transitive dependency versions. With NoSuchMethodError, majority of the time, this is the problem. Use `mvn dependency:tree` to see all the transitive dependencies.

Comment: I tried mvn dependency:tree in terminal and I got an error at the end that one of my modules was not found in local mvn repo. So I now I am running mvn install to see if it goes away.

Answer (score 0):

In Maven, when you have a transitive dependency shared between multiple direct dependencies at the same distance (or depth), the one that will end up in your dependency tree will be one coming from the first direct dependency in order of appearance.

Since `com.microsoft.azure:azure-keyvault:1.0.0` appears first in your POM, the project will end up with version `1.0.0` of `com.microsoft.azure:azure-client-runtime`, which is where the class that would contain the `proxy()` method resides. The problem is that this method was introduced until version `1.1.0`

What you can do here is swapping the order in which the Azure Key Vault and Azure Client Authentication dependencies appear. Another thing you can do is directly declare which version of azure-client-runtime you want to use in your POM:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-client-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You should also consider moving onto the new versions of the [EventHubs](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/eventhubs/azure-messaging-eventhubs) and [Key Vault](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/keyvault) libraries :)